# How to Draw OpenMesh using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, openmesh

i'm working on a project where i'm using **OpenMesh** to read *stl* and *obj* files and draw them on the screen using **openGL**.
i've been doing the following,

```
#include <OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/TriMesh_ArrayKernelT.hh>
#include <OpenMesh/Core/IO/MeshIO.hh>

OpenMesh::TriMesh_ArrayKernelT<> mesh;

std::vector<point> vertices;
std::vector<point> normals;

void readMesh(std::string file)
{
    OpenMesh::IO::read_mesh(mesh, file);

    mesh.requestFaceNormals();
    mesh.request_vertex_normals();
    mesh.updateNormals();

    vertices.clear();
    normals.clear();

    for (auto face : mesh.faces())
    {
        for (auto vertex : mesh.fv_range(face))
        {
            auto point = mesh.point(vertex);
            auto normal = mesh.normal(face);

            vertices.push_back(point);
            normals.push_back(normal);
        }
    }

    mesh.releaseFaceNormals();
    mesh.releaseVertexNormals();
}
```

and when drawing i just pass the `vertices` and `normals` vectors to the vertex shader like this

```
void paint()
{
    glSetAttributeArray(0, vertices.data());
    glSetAttributeArray(1, normals.data());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length());
}
```

where the vertex shader looks like this:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 color = vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0);

    vec4 P = vec4(position, 0);
    vec4 N = vec4(normal, 0);

    vec3 L = vec3(20, 20, 20) - position;
    vec3 V = -position;
    N = normalize(N);
    L = normalize(L);
    V = normalize(V);
    vec3 R = reflect(-L, vec3(N));
    vec3 diffuse = max(dot(vec3(N), L), 0.0) * color.rgb;
    vec3 specular = pow(max(dot(R, V), 0.0), 0.2) * vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    color = vec4(color.a * (ambient + diffuse + specular), color.a);
    color = clamp(color, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_Color = color;
    gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * P;
}
```

and the fragment shader is:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

this produces pretty good results, but the idea of having another copy of the vertices and normals stored in another location (`normals` and `vertices`) to be able to draw the mesh looks very counter-intuitive.

i was wondering if i can use **openGL** buffers with **openMesh** to optimize this. i've been searching for anything concerning this topic for a while but found nothing.

Comment: in other words
how can I eliminate the need for the `vertices` and `normal` vectors?

Answer (score 1):

See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification). You can create 2 [Vertex Buffer Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) for the verticex cooridantes and nortmal vertors:

```cpp
GLuint vbos[2];
glGenBuffers(2, vbos);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(vertices[0]), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size() * sizeof(normals[0]), normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

If you use OpenGL 3.0 or later, then you can specify a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) a nd state the vertex specification:

```cpp
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

When you want to draw the mesh, then it is sufficient to bind the VAO:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length());
```

If you use OpenGL 2.0, the you cannot create a VAO, thus you have to specify the arrays of generic vertex attribute data, before drawing the mesh:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[1]);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length());
```

---

Furthermore note, that the attribute indices are not guaranteed to be 0 and 1. The attribute indices can be any arbitrary number.

If you would use GLSL version 3.30 the it would be possible to set the attribute indices in the shader code by [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index).
Anyway you an define the attribute indices by [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) before linking the program or retrieve the attribute indices by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) after linking the program.

Comment: may be I couldn't address this correctly, but what i'm trying to say is: **how can I eliminate the need for the `vertices` and `normals` vectors?**
as far as I can see from this solution, they are still being used. the idea is that I want to reduce the memory consumption per Mesh.

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud Do you mean you want to combine the vertex coordinate and normal vector to an attribute tuple with 6 components?

Comment: not exactly, i just want to use the vertices and normals data stored in the mesh structure directly to remove the need for the two nested for loops in the `readMesh()` function

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud So the question has nothing to do with OpenGL or GLSL, it is just a c++ coding question?

Comment: not a C++ Coding question, it's almost an OpenMesh question.

Comment: @MostafaMahmoud The question is neither about the OpenGL instructions nor about the shader code. Anyway, what you want to achieve is not possible, because the normal vector is per face, but you have to specify the normal vectors per vertex.